# Use a variable as template variable

Tags: meteor

I have a page header template, which has a title variable like so:

```
{{> pageHeader title="questions"}}

<template name="pageHeader">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</template>
```

This works fine. But I use i18n to set my titles, like `{{i18n 'title'}}`.
How can I use this in the template call? When I use this it doesn't work:

```
{{> pageHeader title="{{i18n 'title'}}"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet on master branch of meteor but on develop: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5066
If you update to the 1.2 release candidate you can already use this feature.
Update to the rc:

```
meteor update --release METEOR@1.2-rc.10
```

Use the nested sub-expressions:

```
{{> pageHeader title=(i18n 'title')}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will wait till it is officially released and then use these nested sub-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the i18n in your .js file.

Your template would be

`{{> pageHeader title=i18nTitle}}`

and you'd have a helper that would solve for the i18n

`Template.xxx.helpers({ 
    i18nTitle: function() { 
      return i18nMethod('title'); 
    } 
});`